# Add relationship with secondary where common column between two children

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a situation that's **similar** to the below scenario

```
CREATE TABLE common_parent (
    parent_id,
    other_cols
)

CREATE TABLE child_one (
    child_one_id,
    parent_id,
    common_attribute,
    other_cols
)

CREATE TABLE child_two (
    child_two_id,
    parent_id,
    other_cols
)

CREATE TABLE child_two_child (
    child_two_child_id,
    child_two_id,
    common_attribute,
    other_cols
)
```

I am adding relationships to the `child_one` orm.  I have a relationship to `child_two` defined based off the `parent_id` matching (giving a list of returned objects)

```
child_twos = relationship('ChildTwo', uselist=True)
```

What I am trying to do: Add a relationship to `child_two_child` with the additional restriction of the `common_attribute`

```
child_two_children = relationship('ChildTwoChild', secondary='ChildTwo', uselist=True)
```

This works and gives results, but it fails to apply the additional restriction of `child_one.common_attribute == child_two_child.common_attribute`.  How can I alter the above to achieve this?  (I do not have the ability to change the DDL, as it's pre-existing legacy design)